# Pdf creation from current context is not clear

Tags: ios, ipad, core-graphics

I am generating pdf from current context using core graphics functions. while running the app in some iPad (with same iOS) the pdf generated is not clear.

I am using example code in the following link for generating pdf

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/GeneratingPDF/GeneratingPDF.html

Comment: Sooo welcome to stack overflow. I'm not going to down vote you, it's a common misconception. New users think we can read minds ;) well not yet. Your going to have to provide a more thorough example, include relevant code, and any other information related to how you generate the PDF. In SO, a vague question creates too many possible answers which can cause people to do the run around instead of answering it right off the bat to begin with. A vague question usually also gets horrible answers.

Comment: i ll post code that i am using to generate the pdf, the thing is this code works perfect in iPad 2 but not in any other iPad